# How can I open MATLAB R2022a hosted on macOS over X11?

Tags: ssh, x11, macos, matlab

Question: **How can I open MATLAB R2022a hosted on macOS over X11?**

I recently installed MATLAB R2022A on macOS, replacing an older Mac with an old 2017 installation. The license is a Network Named User license, and the license is working. However, we are having a problem with using MATLAB over X11. I should note that X11 is working in general, with both IDL and xeyes working over the same client-host connection, so this is a MATLAB configuration or application issue.

MATLAB works when used locally on the new Mac by a named user. It opens graphically when the app is double-clicked, and in Terminal we can call the $MATLABROOT/bin/matlab binary, which also opens the GUI app.
When users SSH into the system and use that binary, MATLAB opens headlessly. This is also true when they use the "-desktop" argument (which should not be needed, but we tested). Additionally, when we run MATLAB in this headless mode and then use the command "desktop" receive an error message:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2022a.app/bin/matlab -desktop

                                                < M A T L A B (R) >
                                      Copyright 1984-2022 The MathWorks, Inc.
                                 R2022a Update 3 (9.12.0.1975300) 64-bit (maci64)
                                                   June 2, 2022
 
To get started, type doc.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
 
>> desktop
Error using desktop
The Desktop is not available in this configuration
Error in desktop
 
>>
```

I called Mathworks over this issue and received a reply that they didn't provide assurance of remote usability, or support for remote usage.

In MATLAB 2017 this was all seamless. A user would see the application GUI over X11 when the user executed the binary over SSH.

X11 forwarding is enabled in sshd_config on the server and I stage an ssh_config file on all related clients which includes X11 forwarding automatically. All other X11 purposes, such as IDL and xeyes, are working.

Comment: You do enable x11 forwarding in your ssh, right?

Comment: By the way, it might be more pleasant to use vnc, rdp or a similar technology if the connection isn't purely local

Comment: Yes, I failed to mention, but X11 forwarding is enabled in sshd_config on the server and I stage an ssh_config file on all related clients which includes X11 forwarding automatically. All other X11 purposes, such as IDL and xeyes, are working.